# несколько input в sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, html, alert, sweetalert

Есть такой код:

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Creating a new room',
    input: 'number',
    inputPlaceholder: 'number of players',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Create',
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
});
```

Но когда я попытался добавить второй input ничего не получилось. Кто-то может поомочь?

Answer (score 0):

Читайте внимательнее документацию

```js
const { value: formValues } = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Multiple inputs',
  html:
    '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input">' +
    '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input">',
  focusConfirm: false,
  preConfirm: () => {
    return [
      document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
      document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
    ]
  }
})

if (formValues) {
  Swal.fire(JSON.stringify(formValues))
}
```